# Distribution of collision times for 2-D diffusion in a area of radius $R$ with concentric disc of radius $r<R$ and absorbing boundaries

Tags: probability-distributions

I'm trying to derive the time probability distribution function of collision times $p_R(t)$ and $p_r(t)$ for a time-zero uniform random concentration of $N$ diffusing particles with diffusion coefficient $D$ for a circular area of radius $R$ and concentric disc $r<R$. Once a particle hits a surface at $r$ or $R$ it is annihilated/absorbed.
$p_\rho(t)dt$ is the probability of a particle hitting and being absorbed by the circle of radius $\rho$ (where $\rho$ is outer $R$ or inner $r$) between time $t$ and $t+dt$. I've written a Monte Carlo engine to simulate but would like a closed-form solution.

Comment: It's going to be some mess with Bessel functions.  Can you write the diffusion equation?

Comment: diffusion equation is $\frac{\partial{C}}{\partial{t}} + D\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial r^2} +D\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial C}{\partial r} = 0$

Comment: what would boundary conditions be?

Comment: The boundary condition should be that the concentration is zero on the absorbing boundaries.  So you need appropriate linear combinations of Bessel functions.

Comment: shouldn't there also be a boundary condition that concentration flux at inner cylinder is inward (-$\hat{r}$)and that concentration flux at outer cylinder is outward (+$\hat{r}$)

Comment: No, the concentration will start positive everywhere and so will remain so; the slopes of the concentration at the inner and outer boundaries will have the correct signs by virtue of the equations of motion.  No special condition is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $\dot\rho = D\nabla^2 \rho$, where $\rho$ is the density; given the radial symmetry, $\nabla^2 \rho =\partial_r^2 \rho + \frac{1}{r}\partial_r \rho$.  Decaying eigenfunctions (such that $\dot\rho = -D k^2\rho$) will be solutions to $\partial_r^2 \rho + \frac{1}{r}\partial_r \rho + k^2 \rho = 0$, which are the ordinary Bessel functions of the first and second kinds, $J_0(kr)$ and $Y_0(kr)$.  (The Bessel functions of the second kind are singular at the origin, so we can only include them because we're working in $0 < R_{\text{min}} \le r \le R_{\text{max}}$.)  You need linear combinations that vanish at $R_{\text{min}}$ and $R_{\text{max}}$: $$a_k J_0(k R_{\text{min}})+b_k Y_0(k R_{\text{min}}) = a_k J_0(k R_{\text{max}})+b_k Y_0(k R_{\text{max}}) = 0.$$
Only for (infinitely many) special values of $k$ will the necessary condition be met for a nontrivial solution: $$J_0(kR_{\text{min}}) Y_0(kR_{\text{max}}) - Y_0(kR_{\text{min}}) J_0(kR_{\text{max}})=0.$$  The functions $a_k J_0(kr) + b_k Y_0(kr)$ at these special values will form an orthogonal basis; in particular, you'll find that
$$
\int_{R_{\text{min}}}^{R_{\text{max}}}(a_k J_0(kr) + b_k Y_0(kr))(a_l J_0(lr) + b_l Y_0(lr))\cdot r dr \propto \delta_{k,l}.
$$
You can use this to write your initial condition as $\rho(r, t=0)=\sum C_k (a_k J_0(kr)+b_k Y_0(kr))$ for some coefficients $C_k$, and then $\rho(r,t)=\sum C_k(a_k J_0(kr) + b_k Y_0(kr))\exp(-Dk^2t)$ for all later times.

Comment: Turns out the collision time distribution, being the weight sum of exponentials with different decay rates, fits well to a 'stretched exponential' or Weibull curve. Thanks again!